# How to reduce import time of blender module in python

Tags: python, server, blender

I was working on a project that renders images on server and then the server send it to the client. The server is current AWS lambda function which runs a python script. This script has bpy module involved. But the problem is that importing that module is taking too much time. I want to somehow reduce that time so that my overall function costs and runtime is reduced. Any sort of help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you come up with anything? I can think of things to do on a private server but they wouldn't work with AWS lambda.

Comment: Not yet. I can go for things other than AWS lambda as well. But what I need in that case is scalability and can handle multiple clients together.

Comment: Now if you are setting up your own server/s, you can copy the bpy module to a ram disk to eliminate disk IO. You can pre-start instances that are called several times between restarts, consider how apache can preload several workers before giving them anything to do. These are things that you can't setup with lambda. You can setup AMIs configured to work that way from startup and automate the number of instances started/kept running.

Comment: That will solve the problem of import. But when I render an image it takes almost 100% of CPU. If many users are using it. It will serve them one after the other. I want to serve them all together.

Comment: You should expect rendering to use all the cpu it can. First step is to make renders as fast as possible, second is controlling how many machines are rendering at once. Evee is faster than cycles so should be considered first. For cycles you can set how many cpus are used - in `bpy.context.render` you will find `threads` and `threads_mode`. I would recommend you setup composite nodes that use the new [OIDN](https://youtu.be/wbpMNr0PR7M) with small sample sizes. For help scripting blender ask at [BSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I am not actually using any of these renderers, Cycles or Evee. I am using the simple renderer of blender.

Comment: The old internal renderer uses the same threads property. In 2.80 that render engine was replaced with eevee.

Comment: Oh. Ok thanks for your help. I will try this one. It will be difficult but hopefully will work for me

Comment: You can actually render scene on Lambda? Can you share info on how did you build the script? I cant make it work. @SamiullahJamil

Comment: You can use bpy-lambda python library and simply use all the provided functions with bpy except the GUI functions.